# Is there a way for a Slack CLI tool to proceed through the V2 OAuth access token flow without standing up an entire web site?

Tags: oauth-2.0, command-line-interface, slack-api

I have a CLI tool that requires search access, on behalf of the user. I've set up an application on our team's workspace with all of the right scopes and configuration.

However, I am dismayed at how oppressive the [OAuth access token process](https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2) is for CLI tools.  Step 1 in their process is to provide a link to a custom web site that has an "Add to Slack" button. This already extends a simple CLI tool into requiring an entire web site, but the button is merely a static URL with parameters about the app and scopes.  So far, a static page from Confluence, GitHub, or some other wiki-based project space would be enough.

Step 2 is where the user grants access to the application through their browser.  However, Step 3 is where the action redirects to a special, dynamic page that requires access to take a special `code`, and translate it into an actual usable token for the user to plug into the CLI configuration. This extra step requires a special web page that Slack does *not* provide to do the translation, instead of just handing a token directly to the user.

Even worse, the [API call](https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.v2.access) requires secret `client_id` and `client_secret` parameters that would be plain as day in an shared or open-source CLI tool. (Despite the API documentation saying otherwise, both of these parameters are actually required.)

For example, [Slackcat](https://github.com/bcicen/slackcat) requires a one-page [special web site](http://slackcat.chat/) expressly for the purposes of fielding OAuth requests.  This is a web page that cannot be opened to the public because it would reveal the secret parameters.  Unfortunately, Slackcat does not have the right scope levels I need, so I can't just borrow its web site for token generation.

Is there a better way to sidestep this process and allow a simple CLI tool to just get the right user access token it needs?

Comment: If you seek to get the authentication token with some human intervention, for step 3, you can set redirect URL as localhost, then copy the 'code' value from your browser and then use it in oauth.v2.access method to generate token. Store this token securely for future use.

Comment: The oauth.v2.access method still requires embedding the client_id/client_secret in plaintext within the tool, exposing it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 is fundamentally built around web browsers. The entire point is to allow the user's web browser to be redirected to the OAuth2 provider's website for password entry, so that the user's credentials are never visible to you or pass through any infrastructure you control.

This necessarily involves spawning a browser and sending it to a site you control to begin the OAuth2 flow by setting up state and redirecting the user to the OAuth2 provider, and then complete the OAuth2 flow by handling the redirect *back* from the OAuth2 provider and performing the code/token exchange. You can't do *any* of this with a static site, you need a web service.

> Is there a better way to sidestep this process and allow a simple CLI tool to just get the right user access token it needs?

No. If there were, it would be a vulnerability in OAuth2 that should be fixed, not exploited to bypass the **entire point** of OAuth2.

Comment: Then how do I ask a user to provide a token in a more traditional manner than doesn't involve creating an entire web site?  Most other platforms, like GitHub, CloudFlare, JIRA, have an easy way to go into a user profile, create a personal access token, and plug it into a configuration file.